# Can't find button inside div with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a button with selenium but it is being impossible. These are the solutions that I have tried and none have worked:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ml-auto']/button[.='SELECT FILES']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='SELECT FILES']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//button[class='btn btn-primary ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched']")))
```

And this is the HTML code (I need to click the first button):

```
<div class="ml-auto">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" ngf-select="" ng-model="$ctrl.files" ngf-multiple="true" accept=".yml,text/yaml,application/zip,application/x-zip-compressed" ngf-accept="'application/x-zip-compressed,application/zip,text/yaml,.yml'" ngf-change="$ctrl.fileSelected($files, $event)">
        SELECT FILES
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="2" ng-disabled="!$ctrl.validate()" ng-click="$ctrl.upload()" translate="" disabled="disabled">START UPLOAD</button>
</div>
```

I can find the div, but not the button inside.

Comment: If you can find the div, then use a CSS selector: `div.ml-auto > button`, it will take the first button inside the div container.

Comment: How? Yes, I can find the div with div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ml-auto')

Comment: With find by css method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with below xpath :

```
//button[contains(@class, 'ng-not-empty') and @ng-model='$ctrl.files']
```

or even better css selector would be  :

```
div.ml-auto button.btn.btn-primary.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-not-empty.ng-touched
```

and I see you are using `//` in css selector, it should not be done like that, Instead do it like this  :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ml-auto button.btn.btn-primary.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-not-empty.ng-touched"))).click()
```

Comment: Works! Thanks. Could you tell me why the way I tried it didn't work for me? I do not get it.

Comment: `SELECT FILES` - does not looks like a normal text, looks more like a text node. Is it wrapped in a double quotes ?

Comment: Nope, at first glance it looks like a button like any other.

Comment: can you try with `//button[text()='SELECT FILES']` instead, it should be working fine too. if not then you can go to dev tools (by pressing f12 in chrome) and then go to element tab -> do a CTRL +  F and then paste this `//button[text()='SELECT FILES']` and see if there's at least one entry

Comment: Do you have any more concerns ?

Comment: Not at the moment, thank you very much. I am new to Selenium and the truth is that it is quite complex, it has many things. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0):

The line:
`WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@class, 'ng-not-empty')")))` will make the script pause for 15secs or until the button element is present.
To click the button you need write for `click` action:

```
button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'ng-not-empty')")
button.click()
```

Comment: will make the script pause for 15secs ,no it ain't true, it would try to fetch the element every 500ms from the DOM till 15 sec